# Is there a list of lenses commonly considered "significant" for each mount?

Tags: lens, lens-mount

I'm in the process of installing a focusing screen on my Pentax and, as it will help me with manual focus, I was thinking it could help me using lenses for other mounts ('cause often the mount's adapters lose the autofocus capability)

So, is there a list of those lenses for each mount that are somehow considered important/representative/famous for each mount?

Comment: I think you need to expand on what you mean by "somehow considered important/representative/famous". Also, important does not necessarily equal representative which does not necessarily equal famous.

Comment: @osullic These are just examples of what OP means by *significant*. The question is about significance, not importance, representativeness, or fame *per se*.

Comment: For something to have *significance*, that *significance* needs to be defined: Historically important, representative of the state of the art (either now or at a historical point in the past), famous, etc. Saying something is *significant* without defining what makes it *significant* is entirely too broad.

Comment: Fot those voting to close because opinion based: the existance of something is not based on an opinion (ok, UFO and such aside). I'm not asking for your opinion about the lenses you think are representative, I'm asking about  the existance of a list. Such a list exists or not, it's not an opinion.

Comment: @motoDrizzt Without a more concrete definition of *significant*, the question is both unclear and subjective. How can one know that a list of lenses includes only "significant" lenses without having an opinion about what that word means and which lenses meet the criteria? Even *with* a more concrete definition, the question is still too broad and possibly a request for resources. Congrats, you've managed to hit 4 out of 5 close reasons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are a multitude of such lists. And every one of them is probably different from every other one of them. Well, unless it has been plagiarized from one of the other list writers. **There is, however, no such list universally recognized as definitive.** (This statement is based upon my own personal history in photography over the last 35 years or so. If there is such a definitive list that is more or less universally accepted by the greater photographic community in the way, for example, that Peterson's *Understanding Exposure* is more often than not on everyone's list of texts beginning photographers should consider, I haven't seen it.)

When it comes to lenses what is significant for you may not be significant for someone else and vice-versa. Lens selection is a very personal choice based on a large number of factors. Rather than try to build a collection of *significant* lenses that you may or may not need, you'd probably be better served to build a collection of lenses that allow you to take the photos you desire to take. Until you can describe *why* you need a certain lens to do something your existing lenses limit you from doing, you don't really need that lens.

Comment: In this case significance is (more) objective. A lens can't be significant **for a mount** if that lens exists for every mount. This question has to do with lenses that exist for each mount, not what lenses motoDrizzt personally should be using.

Comment: Please see the edit above. There's no such universally recognized list.

Comment: That doesn't mean there aren't any *good* lists, or that there isn't a *best* list. If your claim is that all such lists really are totally worthless, I think that merits some explanation. Currently your second paragraph only covers why there's no worthwhile list of lenses *that OP should buy*. Maybe OP can clarify, but I don't think the question is asking for personal recommendations.

Comment: Where does the answer say anything resembling "...all such lists really are totally worthless?" The purpose of photo.stackexchange is not to discuss various possible answers to a question, it is to provide the single *definitive* answer to a question. If there isn't a definitive list then there isn't a definitive list.

Comment: "Universally recognized as definitive" is not the same as "definitive". Again, I just think the claim "there's no definitive list" needs to be supported somehow in the answer. Is it because all mounts have the same lenses? Is it because you can use an adapter to use a lens for a different mount? Is it because any lens can be "translated" into one or more lenses for a different mount to produce the same images?

Comment: To clarify, what I take issue with is that the bulk of the answer-- the entire second paragraph --seems (to me) totally irrelevant. OP isn't asking how to build a collection of significant lenses.

Comment: Logic 101: It's impossible to prove a negative.

Comment: @Era It seems to me from the way the questions is worded that the author *is* looking for a list of "what lenses should I get to take advantage of my shiney new focusing screen?"

Comment: Or, at the least, 'What lenses should I consider?"

Comment: This is something I have to point sooner or later on the main network meta: there is the context and then there is the question, and they are totally different things, and we should be able to distinguish between them. Even if I appreciate the kindness, nowhere in my answer I asked "which lens should I buy" because such a question it's TOTALLY against the rules of the network. So I phrased the question to be totally objective. Now, I'll just let it open for the usual 24 hours, and if no list popup I'll be happy to accept this answer :-)

Comment: @motoDrizzt Yes, the context was clear to me in the question. You could edit the question to clarify what you meant.